# Why is it so difficult to do a hello world in python?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I installed python on my windows 10 machine and wanted to write a script to print hello world on a prompt. The file, hello_world.py, contained two lines of code:

```
print("Hello World!")
input("Press any key to close")
```

First I tried to run it in the Windows command prompt. I navigated to the directory of my file with cd and then entered Python hello_world.py. When I run this I get an empty line without an error.

Second I tried to run my script through notepad++. I opened my script, pressed F5, and selected the location of python.exe (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe). This opens a python shell window with a >>> waiting for a command. However there is no "Hello World!" printed to screen.

Third I tried using py.exe (which I understand is the python launcher).I opened my script in notepad++, pressed F5, and selected the location of python.exe (C:\Windows\py.exe). This opens a prompt running python with the >>> waiting for a command. Again, no "Hello World!".

Lastly I tried launching the script by double clicking. When I do this a window opens up showing that windows is using py.exe. This time the program runs and I get the expected output on the screen.

Could someone please explain to me why doing something so simple is so difficult. Also there are so many posts online with different suggestions which simply don't work. I suspect this is due to different operating systems and setups. Perhaps someone knows of a simple hello world tutorial based on a python installation that actually works on windows 10? I suspect I am also missing some key ideas here which is why I am struggling so much. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: O,o python can't be easier on windows. You have your python installed in windows? Then do a right click on the `hello_world` file, Choose `Edit with IDLE`, press f5. Done. ALSO: I wouldn't recommend anaconda if you are starting, it's not needed at all. ALSO: As for the CMD, if you added python to PATH (it's an option of the installer) you can just type `python hello_world.py` and that's it, but make sure CMD is run from the right folder :P

Comment: Since double clicking worked, it sounds like .py file association is correct and just cd to directory and run `hello_world` should work. As for why `Python hello_world.py` didn't work... not sure. You could `where Python` to see if you're running the python you think you are. If you've fiddled around and written a file called "python.py" it could be the thing that's running.

Comment: And `py hello_world.py` should work also. Depending on your distribution, it may be a "chooser" for the current python. If you only have one python, its not a big deal. But handy in virtual envs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming your code is

```py
print("Hello World!")
input("Press any key to close")
```

and not

```py
print("Hello World!") input("Press any key to close")
```

To run a python file, all I have to do is `py file.py` and it works fine. I have also seen people do `python file.py` on windows, and `python3 file.py` is usually used on linux. I am not sure what you will have to use, but I think you should try `py file.py` from the terminal. Also, you can open the file in the default IDLE Python installs (File > Open), and run in that (Run > Run Module)

Also, if that doesn't work, you can take a quick read at this [website I found](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/)

Also,
Make sure your **file** isn't itself called python.py

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked :) I used the windows command prompt and the command py file.py. I also ran the script file in python IDLE and I got the expected output. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help 